# Loop through foreach without knowing the index

Tags: php

I would like to Loop throught `services` but I don't know the index name. They come randomly, example I got `8` and `9` but I do not know them.

```
"2": {
    "first_name": "khalfan",
    "last_name": "mussa",
    "date": "2017-06-06 09:21:36",
    "gender": "male",
    "services": {
        "8": {
            "name": "See a Doctor",
            "results": ""
    },
         "9": {
            "name": "Kichocho",
            "results": "FD- 73"
              }
    }
},
```

Comment: You don't need to know the index for `foreach`. `foreach` gives you the index.

Comment: so use `foreach()`. what's the issue there? what is not working or what issue you are facing?

Comment: How can I archive

Comment: Thanks, @Don'tPanic but if you want  to loop on `$service[8]['name']`, do you mind the index `8` there. What if I don't know the Index `8` @Alive to Die

Comment: Are you wanting to iterate the values in just the _first_ item in services? Can you edit the question to explain more of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

From @Alive to Die answer, I made some changes and I think this code will loop in your services no matter the index.

```
 $array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array as $values) {
    foreach ($values as $keys => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
                if (is_array($val)) {
                    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
                        echo $k . ":" . $v . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have json stored in $json variable.

```
$json = json_decode($json);
foreach($json as $entry) {
 foreach($entry['services'] as $services) {
   //$services['name']
   //and other data here
 }
}
```

You don't need to know the index while using foreach but you can get index from it.

Comment: Thank you , but which `$service` you are looping. Remember there are `$service[8]['name]` and `$service[8]['result']`

Answer (score 0):

The following are four available options:

```
<?php
$arr = ["2" => [
          ["first_name"=> "khalfan",
           "last_name"=> "mussa",
           "date"=>"2017-06-06 09:21:36",
           "gender"=> "male"], 
          ["services" => 
             ["8" => ["name" => "See a Doctor","results"=> ""],
              "9" => ["name"=> "Kichocho","results"=> "FD- 73"]
             ]
          ]
]];

for ($i=0, $max=count($arr["2"]); $i < $max; $i++) {
      if ( isset( $arr["2"][$i]["services"])) {
        $a = $arr["2"][$i]["services"];
        foreach($a as $e) {
           echo $e["name"],"\t";
           echo $e["results"],"\n";
        }
      }
      continue;

}
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/YjRrs)

The advantage here is that the code does work with a foreach as per the OP's request.  But the code is involved and not as fast as it could be, owing to that if conditional.

Another solution that is faster:

```
<?php
$arr = ["2" => [
          ["first_name"=> "khalfan",
           "last_name"=> "mussa",
           "date"=>"2017-06-06 09:21:36",
           "gender"=> "male"], 
          ["services" => 
             ["8" => ["name" => "See a Doctor","results"=> ""],
              "9" => ["name"=> "Kichocho","results"=> "FD- 73"]
             ]
          ]
]];
$count = count($arr["2"]);
$last = $count - 1; // b/c of zero-based indexing

foreach ($arr as $e) {
      foreach($e[$last]["services"] as $a) {
           echo $a["name"],"\t";
           echo $a["results"],"\n";
      }
}

// Or an easier solution without resorting to foreach:
array_walk_recursive($arr,function($item,$key) {
          if ($key == "name") echo $item,"\t";
          if ($key == "results") echo $item,"\n";
});
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/cchO6)

Whether $arr["2"] contains two elements or more as long as the last one is the "services" associate array, this foreach code works.  But, this type of "array walk" can best be carried out with a built-in function designed for this very purpose, [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive).  With this function, you don't have to worry about how to construct the perfect foreach; the iteration occurs behind the scenes and all you need is to supply a callback. array_walk_recursive will drill down to the "services" element and if there is one or more associative arrays with keys of "name" and "results", then their respective values display.

The fourth possibility is one of those "why would you" situations.  Why take an array and json_encode it and then json_decode it back to an array and then apply array_walk_recursive?  But, the code does work:

```
<?php
$arr = ["2" => [
          ["first_name"=> "khalfan",
           "last_name"=> "mussa",
           "date"=>"2017-06-06 09:21:36",
           "gender"=> "male"], 
          ["services" => 
             ["8" => ["name" => "See a Doctor","results"=> ""],
              "9" => ["name"=> "Kichocho","results"=> "FD- 73"]
             ]
          ]
]];
$result=json_decode(json_encode($arr),true);
array_walk_recursive($result, function($value,$key){
   if ($key == "name" ) { echo $value,"\t";}
   if ($key == "results") { echo $value,"\n";} 
});
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/8hO6Y)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I got `Undefined offset: 0` @slevy1

Comment: @Cholowao Thanks for your feedback; see if the revised code works for you.